Implementing generic TryFrom<T> for Option<T> doesn't work
I use TryFrom to convert my type to some concrete types.
I tried to implement TryFrom<T> for Option<T> as a blanket implementation where T refers to those concrete types, but I couldn't make it work.
Simplified example (without failure paths for the sake of example):
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq)]
pub struct MyStruct;

impl TryFrom<&MyStruct> for u32 {
    type Error = ();
    fn try_from(_value: &MyStruct) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
        Ok(42)
    }
}


/*impl<'a, T: TryFrom<&'a MyStruct>> TryFrom<&'a MyStruct> for Option<T> {
    type Error = <T as TryFrom<&'a MyStruct>>::Error;
    
    fn try_from(value: &'a MyStruct) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
        <T as TryFrom<&'a MyStruct>>::try_from(value).map(Some)
    }
}*/

#[test]
fn test_option() {
    assert_eq!(Option::<u32>::try_from(&MyStruct), Ok(Some(42)));
}

error[E0277]: the trait bound `Option<u32>: TryFrom<&MyStruct>` is not satisfied
  --> src/lib.rs:22:16
   |
22 |     assert_eq!(Option::<u32>::try_from(&MyStruct), Ok(Some(42)));
   |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `From<&MyStruct>` is not implemented for `Option<u32>`, which is required by `Option<u32>: TryFrom<_>`
   |
   = help: the following other types implement trait `From<T>`:
             <Option<&'a T> as From<&'a Option<T>>>
             <Option<&'a mut T> as From<&'a mut Option<T>>>
             <Option<T> as From<T>>
   = note: required for `&MyStruct` to implement `Into<Option<u32>>`
   = note: required for `Option<u32>` to implement `TryFrom<&MyStruct>`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `Option<u32>: From<&MyStruct>` is not satisfied
  --> src/lib.rs:22:16
   |
22 |     assert_eq!(Option::<u32>::try_from(&MyStruct), Ok(Some(42)));
   |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `From<&MyStruct>` is not implemented for `Option<u32>`, which is required by `Option<u32>: TryFrom<&MyStruct>`
   |
   = help: the following other types implement trait `From<T>`:
             <Option<&'a T> as From<&'a Option<T>>>
             <Option<&'a mut T> as From<&'a mut Option<T>>>
             <Option<T> as From<T>>
   = note: required for `&MyStruct` to implement `Into<Option<u32>>`
   = note: required for `Option<u32>` to implement `TryFrom<&MyStruct>`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.

Playground
If I enable commented-out part:
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq)]
pub struct MyStruct;

impl TryFrom<&MyStruct> for u32 {
    type Error = ();
    fn try_from(_value: &MyStruct) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
        Ok(42)
    }
}


impl<'a, T: TryFrom<&'a MyStruct>> TryFrom<&'a MyStruct> for Option<T> {
    type Error = <T as TryFrom<&'a MyStruct>>::Error;
    
    fn try_from(value: &'a MyStruct) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
        <T as TryFrom<&'a MyStruct>>::try_from(value).map(Some)
    }
}

#[test]
fn test_option() {
    assert_eq!(Option::<u32>::try_from(&MyStruct), Ok(Some(42)));
}

error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `TryFrom<&MyStruct>` for type `Option<_>`
  --> src/lib.rs:12:1
   |
12 | impl<'a, T: TryFrom<&'a MyStruct>> TryFrom<&'a MyStruct> for Option<T> {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: conflicting implementation in crate `core`:
           - impl<T, U> TryFrom<U> for T
             where U: Into<T>;

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0119`.

Playground
I receive missing implementation error for the former example, while I receive conflicting implementation error for the latter. What am I missing here?

Two implementations A and B conflicting doesn't mean that A provides everything that B would, your specific implementation can still be missing. I think you'll have to add impl TryFrom<&MyStruct> for Option<u32> and every other Option<T> you want explicitly.

This sounds a bit confusing. I don't think I understood the rationale. I think I will create a separate trait like FromMyStruct to avoid dealing with these subtleties. Thanks.

Just because there is an overlap between A (impl<T, U> TryFrom<U> for T where U: Into<T>) and B (your generic implementation for Option<T>) doesn't mean that A covers your specific usecase (TryFrom<&'a MyStruct> for Option<u32>)

You are aware of Result::ok()? Or what is your purpose for this deepening?

This is a minimal reproducible example. TryFrom is called later from a generic context.

@cafce25 I see. What's the rationale there though? Why does an unmaterialized possibility prevents an implementation that doesn't have intersection in practice? This is very surprising behavior. Or is it somehow intersecting in a way that I didn't understand?

@cafce25 Could you also give any concrete examples to that overlap you're referring in terms of T and U?

T = Option<T>, U = &'a MyStruct the compiler only looks if an overlap is possible typewise, not if one is actually present, that way adding an implementation can't become a breaking change which requires a major version bump, but always can be done in a minor version.

This is the code snippet that compiles and passes tests:
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq)]
pub struct MyStruct;

impl TryFrom<&MyStruct> for u32 {
    type Error = ();
    fn try_from(_value: &MyStruct) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
        Ok(42)
    }
}

#[test]
fn test_option() {
    assert_eq!(u32::try_from(&MyStruct), Ok(42));
    assert_eq!(u32::try_from(&MyStruct).map(|x| Some(x)), Ok(Some(42)));

}

The problem is that, for all T, T implements Into<Option<T>>. As it should: all you need to do to convert anything to an Optional form is to wrap Some around it.
For the commented in version, you're trying to implement a specific version of TryFrom<T> when the core library already implements a generic version of it.
For the commented out version, Option<u32> is considered separate from u32, so you never implemented TryFrom<&MyStruct> for it. To get a Result<Option<u32>, ()> from a &MyStruct, use the map method what you get from u32::try_from

Well... It compiles and passes because it tests an entirely different thing. TryFrom is called from a generic context where I can't call map depending on the type.
